# How to avoid piling up callbacks or "callback hell"?

Tags: java

My program makes heavy use of (possibly) asynchronous calls where the return value is not immediately available, thus there are a lot of methods like this:

```
// A simple callback interface
public interface GetFooCallback
{
    void onResult(Foo foo);
};

// A method that magically retrieves a foo
public void getFoo(long fooID, GetFooCallback callback)
{
    // Retrieve "somehow": local cache, from server etc.
    // Not necessarily this simple.
    Foo foo = ...; 

    callback.onResult(foo);
}
```

However, as there are lots of things that are dependent of the last call like this, they start to pile up:

```
// Get foo number 42
fooHandler.getFoo(42, new GetFooCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onResult(final Foo foo)
    {
        // Foo 42 retrieved, get a related Bar object
        barHandler.getBar(foo.getBarID(), new GetBarCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Bar bar)
            {
                // Send a new Zorb(foo, bar) to server
                zorbHandler.sendZorbToServer(new Zorb(foo, bar), new ZorbResponseHandler()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                        // Keep dancing
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure()
                    {
                        // Drop the spoon
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This "works", but it starts to feel rather icky when the pile keeps growing and it's difficult to keep track of what's happening. So, the question is: How do I avoid this pile-up? As I've googled "callback hell", many places suggest RxJava or RxAndroid, but I haven't really found any examples showing how one would convert something like the aforementioned example into a more concise whole.

Comment: Not a substantional improvement, but with Java 8 lambdas you could at least cut down on boilerplate code here.

Comment: use future/promise constructs, like my [async lib](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/async/Async_Programming.html#Sequential_Actions)

Comment: @bayou.io with a bit of explanation that seems a very fine answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen - well, it's not a small topic. I gave it a try :)

Answer (score 9):

This is a controversial topic with a lot of opinions; let me focus on a specific solution and try to argue why it is better than callbacks.

The solution is usually known as future, promise, etc; the key point is that an async function does not take a callback; instead, it returns a future/promise that represents the ongoing async action. Here, let me use term `Async` to represent async actions because I feel it's a much better name.

Instead of accepting a callback

```
    void func1(args, Callback<Foo>)
```

return an Async instead

```
    Async<Foo> func2(args)
```

`Async` does contain methods that accept callbacks on completion, therefore `func2` could be used in the similar fashion as `func1`

```
    func1(args, callback);
    // vs
    func2(args).onCompletion( callback )
```

In this regard, `Async` is at least not worse than the callback solution.

Typically, Async are not used with callbacks; instead, Asyncs are chained like

```
func2(args)
    .then(foo->func3(...))
    .then(...)
    ...
```

The first thing to notice is that this is flat, as opposed to callback nesting.

---

Beyond aesthetic reasons, what's the big deal of `Async`? Some people argue that it is essentially the same as callback, just with an alternative syntax. However, there is a big difference.

The biggest secret of OOP is that you can use objects to represent stuff... How is that a secrete? Isn't that OOP-101? But in reality people often forget that.

When we have an Async object to represent the async action, our program can easily do stuff with the action, for example, to pass actions around through APIs; to cancel an action or set a timeout; to compose multiple sequential/parallel actions as one action; etc. These things can be done in the callback solution, however, it is just a lot more difficult and non-intuitive, because there are no tangible objects that the program can play with; instead, the concept of action is only in our head.

The only real judge is whether a solution does simply your application. Here is my [async library](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/async/Async_Programming.html), take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: Note that you'll either need to nest, or make a custom class to return both `foo` and the value of `barHandler.getBar(...)`, since you need both `foo` and `bar` to be accessible from the same function to call `sendZorbToSender`.

Comment: @Claudiu - yes, it's a little difficult to pass values across. as a non-purist, sometimes I'll just use a mutable container :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact use case and requirements, there may be different programming approaches or paradigms that may be suitable for your specific task. These may include various forms of [Message Passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) or [Actor models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), [Reactive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) (e.g. with RxJava, which you already mentioned), or in general, some form of [Flow-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming). It might even be possible to use an [Event Bus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) for the exchange of "events" (which are the computed results, in your case).

However, most of them are built on certain infrastructures - particularly, on libraries that require your system to be *modeled* accordingly. For example, your callbacks might have to implement specific interfaces in order to be notified about the (asynchronous) results. Additionally, you will, at some place, have to do the "wiring": You will have to specify which particular callback should be called when a result becomes available - even if this may be as simple as registering this callback for a certain "event type".

---

Of course, it would be possible to build the necessary infrastructure for this manually. You could implement your `FooHandler` class accordingly:

```
class FooHandler
{
    // Maintain a list of FooCallbacks
    private List<FooCallback> fooCallbacks = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addFooCallback(FooCallback fooCallback)
    {
        fooCallbacks.add(fooCallbacks);
    }

    public void getFoo(long fooID)
    {
        // Retrieve "somehow": local cache, from server etc.
        // Not necessarily this simple.
        Foo foo = ...; 

        publish(foo);
    }

    // Offer a method to broadcast the result to all callbacks
    private void publish(Foo foo)
    {
        for (FooCallback fooCallback : fooCallbacks) 
        {
            fooCallback.onResult(foo);
        }
    }
}

class BarHandler implements FooCallback
{
    // Maintain a list of BarCallbacks, analogously to FooHandler 
    ...

    @Override
    public void onResult(Foo foo)
    {
        Object id = foo.getBarID();
        Bar bar = getFrom(id);

        publish(bar);
    }
}
```

So that you can assemble your callback structure with code that looks like this:

```
FooHandler fooHandler = new FooHandler();
FooCallback fooCallback = new BarHandler();
fooHandler.addFooCallback(fooCallback);
...
barHandler.add(new MyZorbResponseHandler());
```

This basically boils down to *not* passing the callbacks as method parameters, but instead maintaining them in a dedicated list. This at least makes the wiring a little easier and more concise. But it would still make the general structure rather "rigid" and not as loosely coupled as it might be with a dedicated infrastructure that models this "Listener"- and information exchange concept in a more abstract form.

---

If your *primary* goal was to avoid the "piling" that you mentioned, in terms of readability and maintainability of the code (or plainly: The indentation level), one approach could be to simply extract the creation of the new callback instances into utility methods.

Although this is certainly no replacement for a full-fledged, sophisticated message-passing architecture, here is a small example what this may look like, based on the code that you provided:

```
class CompactCallbacks
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FooHandler fooHandler = null;
        BarHandler barHandler = null;
        ZorbHandler zorbHandler = null;

        fooHandler.getFoo(42, 
            createFooCallback(barHandler, zorbHandler));
    }

    private static GetFooCallback createFooCallback(
        BarHandler barHandler, ZorbHandler zorbHandler)
    {
        return foo -> barHandler.getBar(
            foo.getBarID(), createGetBarCallback(zorbHandler, foo));
    }

    private static GetBarCallback createGetBarCallback(
        ZorbHandler zorbHandler, Foo foo)
    {
        return bar -> zorbHandler.sendZorbToServer(
            new Zorb(foo, bar), createZorbResponseHandler());
    }

    private static ZorbResponseHandler createZorbResponseHandler()
    {
        return new ZorbResponseHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
                // Keep dancing
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure()
            {
                // Drop the spoon
            }
        };
    }
}

//============================================================================
// Only dummy classes below this line
class FooHandler
{
    public void getFoo(int i, GetFooCallback getFooCallback)
    {
    }
}
interface GetFooCallback
{
    public void onResult(final Foo foo);
}
class Foo
{
    public int getBarID()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
class BarHandler
{
    public void getBar(int i, GetBarCallback getBarCallback)
    {
    }
}
interface GetBarCallback
{
    public void onResult(final Bar bar);
}
class Bar
{
}
class ZorbHandler
{
    public void getZorb(int i, GetZorbCallback getZorbCallback)
    {
    }
    public void sendZorbToServer(Zorb zorb,
        ZorbResponseHandler zorbResponseHandler)
    {
    }
}
interface GetZorbCallback
{
    public void onResult(final Zorb Zorb);
}
class Zorb
{
    public Zorb(Foo foo, Bar bar)
    {
    }
    public int getBarID()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
interface ZorbResponseHandler
{
    void onSuccess();
    void onFailure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help, but here's a design idea that may inspire a solution. The inspiration comes from Python's Twisted. The end result would look like this (explanation follows):

```
Generator<Deferred> theFunc = Deferred.inlineCallbacks(new Generator<Deferred>() {
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        Foo foo = (Foo)yield(fooHandler.getFoo(42));
        Bar bar = (Bar)yield(barHandler.getBar(foo.getBarID());
        try {
            yield(zorbHandler.sendZorbToServer(new Zorb(foo, bar));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Drop the sooon
            return; 
        }
        // Keep dancing
    }
});

theFunc();
```

Note the lack of nesting and callback hell.

---

To explain, I'll explain how it would work in Twisted.
With Twisted, your code would look something like this:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def the_func():
    foo = yield fooHandler.getFoo(42)
    bar = yield barHandler.getBar(foo.getBarID())
    try:
        yield zorbHandler.sendZorbToServer(Zorb(foo, bar))
        # Keep dancing
    except Exception:
        # Drop the spoon

the_func()
```

In this snippet, `the_func` is actually a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that yields [Deferred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/core/howto/defer.html) objects. `fooHandler.getFoo`, instead of taking a callback and then calling the callback with the result, instead returns a Deferred object. Callbacks can be added to the Deferred object, which are called when the object fires. Thus instead of `getFoo` looking something like this:

```
def getFoo(self, value, callback):
    # do some stuff and then in another thread
    doSomeStuffInThread(value, lambda foob: callback(foob))

# Usage:
getFoo(42, myCallback)
```

It looks like this:

```
def getFoo(self, value):
    deferred = Deferred()
    doSomeStuffInThread(value, lambda foob: deferred.callback(foob))
    return deferred

deferred = getFoo(42)
deferred.addCallback(myCallback)
```

Deferreds seem similar, if not the same, as [CompletableFutures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) (compare `addCallback` to `thenApply`).

Then, `defer.inlineCallbacks` magically connects all the callbacks and all the deferreds by doing something like the following:

- Start the generator, getting the first Deferred.
- Add a callback to the first Deferred, which takes the result and sends the result into the generator.
- Repeat with the next Deferred and the next result, and so on, until the generator is exhausted.

---

Perhaps you can implement something similar in Java - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971237/15055) for a generator equivalent (you'll have to modify `yield` to return values), and the [Twisted source code](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.2.0/twisted/internet/defer.py#L1100) for an implementation of `defer.inlineCallbacks`.

Comment: Java doesn't have `yield` or anything like it. Yes, you can hack it together with a thread like the linked solution does, but it's not a whole lot better than what the OP is already doing.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: The code would look a lot neater IMO, but the back-end would be hacky, true. Personally I'm willing to do a lot of back-end hacking to make the front-end code nice, but people's tastes may vary.