# How to call the constructor with the next element of an ArrayList

Tags: java

When calling the constructor, I need to create objects using the next element in the ArrayList

```
public class MinionToy implements ISurprise {

    private static final ArrayList<String> arrMinion = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("Dave", "Carl", "Kevin", "Stuart", "Jerry", "Tim"));

    private static int currentToyIndex = 0;

    private String surpriseName;

    private MinionToy(String minionName) {
        this.surpriseName = minionName;
    }

    public static MinionToy generate() {

        if (currentToyIndex < arrMinion.size()) {
            return new MinionToy(arrMinion.get(currentToyIndex));

        } else {
            currentToyIndex = 0;
        }
        currentToyIndex++;
        return new MinionToy(arrMinion.get(currentToyIndex));

    }

    @Override
    public void enjoy() {
        System.out.println("You have received the minion named: " + this.surpriseName);
    }
}
```

When creating the objects, It should always create it using the next name. Instead it just creates Dave, Dave etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570132/generator-functions-equivalent-in-java might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you never increment the toy index:

```java
 public static MinionToy generate() {

        // if (0 < 4)
        //   return a new miniontoy(arra.get(0)
        // the rest of the code never gets executed.
        if (currentToyIndex < arrMinion.size()) {
            return new MinionToy(arrMinion.get(currentToyIndex));

        } else {
            currentToyIndex = 0;
        }
        currentToyIndex++;
        return new MinionToy(arrMinion.get(currentToyIndex));
```

try:

```java
 public static MinionToy generate() {

        if (currentToyIndex >= arrMinion.size()) {
            currentToyIndex = 0;
        }
        return new MinionToy(arrMinion.get(currentToyIndex++));
 }
```

There was another answer which was deleted that use the modulo operator (%). Since @Bogdan also liked that answer, I have added a variant of it here:

```java
 private static currentToyIndex = -1;      // Important that we start at =1 so that we can get the zero'th element
  public static MinionToy generate() {
    return new MinionToy(arrMinion.get(++currentToyIndex % arrMinion.size());
  }
```

Comment: Remark for the OP:`currentToyIndex++` will increase the value AFTER it is passed to the `get()` method. Otherwise `currentToyIndex` can become equals to size() and result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: @conffusion. You are correct about currentToyIndex++. However, the potential for the Exception is guarded against by the if statement. After the generate method returns the last element from the arrayList, the currentToyIndex will become 6 due to the ++ (i.e. it is now = the arrMinion.size). The next time the generate method is called, the if statement will be: if (index /* i.e. 6 */ == size /* also = 6 */) will be true. Therefore on this subsequent call, the index will be reset back to 0. Thus there should not be any Exception.

Comment: In the original version of the generate method currentToIndex is increased before the call to get() but after the test so then there is a potential error. But your code is correct.

Comment: @Conffusion, oh, i c, you were referring to the OP. Another potential problem in the OP is that if the index was somehow got set to 0 via the else, the index would immediately be incremented to 1. Thus, the 0'th element ("Dave") would never become a "MinionToy". Which is probably good news for Dave - ain't nobody wants to be a Minion's Toy! :-)

Comment: @Bogdan_Buzaianu If this has helped you, could you please accept the answer by clicking on the little grey check next to the top of the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do it. The other answer by @gaborsch, using % was also very elegant. Too bad it was deleted

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why it was deleted, one of my answers was mysteriously deleted (on another post). I will add the % variant to my answer as best as I can. My only thought against % is that it is likely a more expensive operation than the if variant. But in the grand scheme of things, probably it wouldn't make much difference.