# Cartesian product of large number of sets

Tags: java, algorithm

I have `List<List<T>> input` and I need to generate cartesian product from that. I was trying to use `Lists.cartesianProduct(input)` but the problem is that size of the cartesian product is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and method throws exception. All algorithms I found online have similar issues (they are limited by `List` maximum size which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if you want to keep full List functionality). The only solution I thought of would be creating my own list implementation indexed with `long` instead of `int` but I would not be able to use `List` interface and that would be very troublesome so that would really be the last resort. Is there any other way around it? The output doesn't have to be a List as long as I have all of the possible combinations.

Comment: Are you sure you want to generate those in memory?

Comment: Seems like a generator would be the way to go.

Comment: @Kayaman I would prefer it in memory since I would still need to process it further but a solution with saving it to a file would be acceptable workaround so if you could suggest some solution I would be grateful.

Comment: @ggorlen could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @ggorlen native generator like `Stream.generate(Supplier<T>)`?

Comment: That sounds good. I don't know Java actually so I'm probably spreading misinformation. Worth adding to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570132/generator-functions-equivalent-in-java)?

Comment: @ggorlen well, the second answer there does answer the given question with streams, as that's about lazily streaming based on an array and not generating per se, so I'd consider it to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to build a solution that iterates over the cartesian product and calls a user supplied function instead of building a list of them. This way the full product is never in memory. If you prefer to store the result in a file, you can do that too, just supply a function that writes to a file.

```
<T> void cartesianProduct(List<List<T>> items, Consumer<List<T>> consumer) {
    recurse(items, consumer, new ArrayList<>());
}

<T> void recurse(List<List<T>> items, Consumer<List<T>> consumer, List<T> prefix) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        consumer.accept(prefix);
    } else {
        List<T> first = items.get(0);
        List<List<T>> rest = items.subList(1, items.size());
        for (T item : first) {
            prefix.add(item);
            recurse(rest, consumer, prefix);
            prefix.remove(prefix.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For example, this prints the cartesian product to System.out:

```
cartesianProduct(List.of(
    List.of("1", "2"), List.of("A", "B"), List.of("!", "@")
), System.out::println);
```