# Loop and get the last total value

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suppose I have a List and a result of

```
[
  {
      "userTaskId": 10,
      "counter": 1,
      "userName" : "test name one"
  },
  {
      "userTaskId": 10,
      "counter": 2,
      "userName" : "test name two"
  },
  {
      "userTaskId": 10,
      "counter": 3,
      "userName" : "test name three"
  },
  {
      "userTaskId": 20,
      "counter": 1,
      "userName" : "test name"
  },
  {
      "userTaskId": 20,
      "counter": 1,
      "userName" : "test name four"
  },
  {
      "userTaskId": 20,
      "counter": 3,
      "userName" : "test name five"
  },
]
```

and I will loop through it

```
List<UserModel> savedUser = userRepository.findAll();

for (UserModel user: savedUser) {
    Double number = user.getCounter() * 1000;

    /* 
     * number result will be
     * 1000 -> userTaskId: 10
     * 2000 -> userTaskId: 10
     * 3000 -> userTaskId: 10
     * 1000 -> userTaskId: 20
     * 1000 -> userTaskId: 20
     * 3000 -> userTaskId: 20
     */
}
```

Now my question is how can I get the **number total** before it changes to different **userTaskId**. Now I implemented:

```
Double holder = 0D;
Set<Long> test = new HashSet<>();
Double total = 0D;
List<UserModel> savedUser = userRepository.findAll();
for (UserModel user: savedUser) {
    Double number = user.getCounter() * 1000;
    Long userTaskId = user.getTaskId();


    if (test.contains(limitNo)){
         total += number;
    } else {
         // Save the total value to temporary variable before resetting the total
         holder = total;
         System.out.println(holder);
         total = number;

         test.add(userTaskId);
    }

    /* 
     * total result will be
     * 1000 -> userTaskId: 10
     * 3000 -> userTaskId: 10
     * 6000 -> userTaskId: 10 (I want to get this value)
     * 1000 -> userTaskId: 20
     * 2000 -> userTaskId: 20
     * 5000 -> userTaskId: 20 (I want to get this value)
     */
}
```

I wanted to get the value **6000 and 5000** however I only get the value:

```
0.0 and 6000
```

any idea on how can I get those values only?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: jpa mysql...,...

Comment: Why are you not doing this in an SQL query?

Comment: I cannot because this is only the simplified version. That ( * 1000 ) is not the real value I only use it as a sample

Comment: Then you can sort the list on ```userTaskId``` and then iterate.

Comment: And why is ```Double total = 0D;``` inside the ```for``` loop?

Comment: edited sorry..,

Comment: Generators https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971237/495157

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
import :
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

///////////

Map<Long, Double> getResponse(List<UserModel> savedUser) throws Exception{
        Map<Long, Double> ans = savedUser.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(UserModel::getUserTaskId, summingDouble(this::getValue)));
        return ans;
    }

private Double getValue(UserModel  userModel) {
    return userModel.getCounter() * 1000;
}
```

Here is for loop code:

```
savedUser.sort((a,b)-> a.getUserTaskId() <= b.getUserTaskId() ? -1 : 1);
        int len = savedUser.size();
        int prev = 0;
        double total = savedUser.get(0).getCounter() * 1000;
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            if (savedUser.get(i).getUserTaskId() != savedUser.get(prev).getUserTaskId()) {
                // here from prev to i-1 one group
                // total contains summation of this group
                // do your task
                prev = i;
                total = savedUser.get(i).getCounter() * 1000;
            } else {
                total += (savedUser.get(i).getCounter() * 1000);
            }
        }
        //here is another group from prev to len-1
        //total contains summation of this group
        //do your task
```

Comment: Hi I wanted to do this inside the loop is it okay?

Comment: why not use java8 stream feature? if want to use for loop then go sort first then calculate

Comment: I need to do it inside the for loop because. I have other things that has been there it is just not included on the sample code.

Comment: Hi im having this warning Comparator does not return 0 for equal elements

Comment: @Beginner no need to return 0  or use `        savedUser.sort((a,b)-> (int) (a.getUserTaskId() - b.getUserTaskId()));
`

Comment: I only get the first value which is the 6000

Comment: see carefully.  last value always after for loop . i added comment

Comment: Still i only get the first total which is the 6000 maybe we need to check if it is the last element?