# Search in database with like operator and return list of results

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sql-like

Here is my method to searching a specific String:

(I want to do search in title of books table)

```
private static String searchInDB(String keyword) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstore";
    String query = "Select title from books where title like %?% ";
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, keyword);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getString("title");
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}
```

But when i call this method:

```
System.out.println(searchInDB("so"));
```

there is an exception in the result:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which 
is 0).
null
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
...
```

**UPDATE**

I add this code to get all the results, but i got into a infinitive loop with a identical value!

```
String result = searchInDB("so");
    while (result != null) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code so that the wildcards are contained in the parameter, and not in the query, viz:

```
String query = "Select title from books where title like ?";
....
ps.setString(1, "%" + keyword + "%");
```

**Edit**  Re, other question

AFAIK Java has no [yield return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352399/yield-return-in-java) capability, so you'll need to change your method signature.
Currently, you are returning the first result and then never returning to the function.

My Java is pretty basic, but how about:

```
private static List<String> searchInDB(String keyword) {
    List<String> theStrings = new List<String>();
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstore";
    String query = "Select title from books where title like %?% ";
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, keyword);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            theStrings.Add(rs.getString("title"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();

    }
    return theStrings ;
}
```

Comment: I believe you meant to say `if (result != null)` ?

Comment: I try `if(result !=null)` but it returns just one value, but the are several values in DBMS result.

Comment: @user3808021 I've updated - you'll need to return a colleciton of strings