# Getting value to increment and return after each incrementation

Tags: java, methods, return

I am trying to increment a variable from 0-99, and return the value each time, but I'm unsure how i could do this. This is the code i have so far:

```
public int getValue()
{
  if (currentState == COUNTING)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
      value = i;
    }

    return value;      

  } else {
    return super.getValue();   
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how I could modify this, as at the moment it is returning 99. I know why, but do not know how to accomplish what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, strictly speaking you cannot return multiple values from a method call. A method in Java can only return a single primitive value or Object..

Your code returns 99 because the final 'value' of your loop variable 'i' is 99 when for loop finishes to execute. Instead you should try returning your values hold in an Integer Array.

Answer (score 1):

In java a function can only return once; at that point it exits the function. You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980953/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-cs-yield-keyword).

So the short answer is no. If you can give more context as to what you're trying to accomplish, it might be possible to try to help explain a good way to do it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `static` member and increment it on each call.

```
class MyClass
{
   private static int value = 0;
   public int getValue
   {
       if ( value >= 99 )
          return value; //or throw exception, whatever
       else
          return value++;
   }
}
```

EDIT: If your `getValue` is bound to an instance of the class, there's no need to make `value` a `static`. If you want each call on the method to return an increment value, regardless of the object it's called on, you have to make it `static`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve formatting, for each number on its own line, then you will need to append a new line **\n** or **endl**.

If you are trying to simply print 1-99 using a single method and a single return, you will need to use an **array**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a class variable that maintains the value, then return the incremented value each time getValue() is called

```
private int value=0;
public int getValue()
{
  if (currentState == COUNTING)
  { 
    return value++;
  }
  else
    return super.getValue();   
}
```