# I have to return a value from a function that is called multiple times and I am unable to do that

Tags: java, function, loops, return

I am stuck.

The following function is supposed to return `currVm`, an integer. But if I make a `return` I will break the loop and next time when this function is called,the same process will begin again.

What shall I do, so that I continue from where I left off ? I tried making `static` variables but I that didn't help me.

```
@Override
public int getNextAvailableVm() {
    Set<String> dataCenters = confMap.keySet();
    for (String dataCenter : dataCenters) {
        LinkedList<DepConfAttr> list = confMap.get(dataCenter);
        Collections.sort(list, new MemoryComparator());
        int size = list.size() - 1;
        int count = 0;
        while(size >= 0) {
            DepConfAttr dca = (DepConfAttr)list.get(count);
            int currVm = dca.getVmCount();
            int c = 0;
            while(c <= currVm) {
                allocatedVm(currVm);
                c++;
                return currVm;
            }
            count++;
            size--;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `for-each` loop assigns a new `data center` that acts as a key for the `confMap`.The list that I get as a value, is sorted.Then a loop is run till it escapes its size.Inside this `while loop`, another `while loop` is run from where a function named `allocatedVm` of the inherited class is called. A parameter named `currVm` is passed to it.

This is the variable that I need to return. What shall I do to return this variable ? I have to start from I left off. I mean the next call should appear to be the next step, whatever it was, while executing the loop.

Comment: What you want is `yield`. Unfortunately, Java doesn't have `yield`. You'll have to switch to C# for that. :-P

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young There will surely be a way out in Java

Comment: I'm sure there is, but it'll be ugly. :-( `yield` is a very clean and easy-to-read feature. I really do wish Java had `yield`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1980953/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `List<Integer>` object to your class, and change your method as follows:

```
private Iterator<Integer> availableVms = null;
@Override
public int getNextAvailableVm() {
    if (availableVms != null) {
        if (availableVms.hasNext()) {
            return availableVms.next();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Set<String> dataCenters = confMap.keySet();
    for (String dataCenter : dataCenters) {
        LinkedList<DepConfAttr> list = confMap.get(dataCenter);
        Collections.sort(list, new MemoryComparator());
        int size = list.size() - 1;
        int count = 0;
        while(size >= 0) {
            DepConfAttr dca = (DepConfAttr)list.get(count);
            int currVm = dca.getVmCount();
            int c = 0;
            while(c <= currVm) {
                allocatedVm(currVm);
                c++;
                tmp.add(currVm);
            }
            count++;
            size--;
        }
    }
    availableVms = tmp.iterator();
    return availableVms.hasNext() ? availableVms.next() : 0;
}
```

The idea is to pre-generate the entire list, and store its iterator for future use. Before entering the method you check if the `availableVms` iterator has been prepared. If it has been prepared, grab the next item off of it if it's available; otherwise, return zero.

If the list has not been prepared yet, run your algorithm, and add the results to a temporary list `tmp`.  Once the list is ready, grab its iterator, and use it for subsequent invocations.

Comment: so the whole algorithm will execute only once..? and next time when the function is called,`if (availableVms.hasNext())` will always execute..Is that so ? and iterator naturally preserves its state

Comment: @saplingPro Yes, the next time the function executes, `availableVms` wouldn't be `null`, so the `if` at the top would be entered. If you want to reuse the object once the list of vms has been exhausted, you would need to provide a `reset` method that sets `availableVms = null`. You could also reset `availableVms = null` before you return zero to reset iterations.