# Return data from thread before finished task. (JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

Client/server application.
Multiple clients can connect to the server.
For each client connection the server creates new thread.
The client sends data until it closes socket.
So I need that the data, managed by the thread server, should be returned to the main server every time. I can't wait that the thread finishes his job, because i don't know when the client closes connection.
What are the right methods?

Comment: You need something like `C#`'s `yield return`. Try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980953/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-cs-yield-keyword

Comment: You can call a method on the main server and pass the Information.
So the main server can read this Information in it's own fields

Comment: What do you mean, "the main server?"  Aren't you talking about threads that run _in_ the server?  I think that if you can better define what "retuned to the main server" means, then the answer to your question probably will become obvious.

Comment: The main (thread) server creates new threads.
For example the server loop forever until a client connect to it, the server creates new thread for this client. The thread take data from the client and it want to show these data to the server in a GUI.
Repeat this action with many client.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a thread you can pass a shared queue as a parameter. In the thread's body, when you get the data from client, push it to the queue. In your server loop poll the data from the queue and use it. [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) should be suitable. Example:

```
// main server thread
Queue<SomeData> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

// ... loop code, etc
Thread thread = new MyThread(queue);

// in thread responsible for GUI updates
SomeData data = queue.poll();
if (data != null) // do something

// client connection thread
SomeData data = ... // received from client
queue.offer(data);
```

Comment: The problem here is that the data update is possible only when the server gets a client connection, because it waits in the ServerSocket.accept() method.

Comment: Hence you need another thread responsible for data updates because accept() blocks the thread in which it is executed. Spawn a thread to do updates to GUI and only then start listening for connections