# .Net 'yield return' equivalent in Java

Tags: java

I'm looking for .NET yield return equivalent in java.
I've found a lot of examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980953/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-cs-yield-keyword). But when I'm using libraries proposed in post like [this](https://github.com/domlachowicz/java-generators) or [this](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/Yield) I have compiler error "Yield outside of switch expression". Something has changed? I'm using java 21.

Comment: but what do you want to achieve? Probably in java it's different way of doing what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java 14 and [JEP 361](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361), `yield` is a *restricted identifier* for use in switch expressions. Given you haven't provided actual code in your question, it is hard to be sure, but I think your question is answered by the JEP:

> Rather than being a keyword, `yield` is a restricted identifier (like
> `var`), which means that classes named `yield` are illegal. If there
> is a unary method `yield` in scope, then the expression `yield(x)`
> would be ambiguous (could be either a method call, or a `yield`
> statement whose operand is a parenthesized expression), and this
> ambiguity is resolved in favor of the `yield` statement. If the method
> invocation is preferred then the method should be qualified, with
> `this` for an instance method or the class name for a static method.

In other words, if you get the error for method calls of the form `yield(x)`, use `this.yield(x)` or `SomeClass.yield(x)` (if it is a static method) instead.

That said, you should probably be using some form of `Stream` instead of trying to exactly emulate .NET yield.